# Python fibonacci unexpecred indent

Tags: python, arrays, indentation, fibonacci

Im new to code and learning python . I got homework to make print Fibonacci 
numbers for N = 11 and N = 200 using method called Memoization . I found solution but when im running the code i getting two things : 1 .

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      **File "python", line 7
        if n== 1:
        ^**
**IndentationError: unexpected indent**
```

and second i got empty result sometime when im running. what is wrong which the code :

```
def fibonacci (n) :
 # If we have cached the value, then return it 
 if n in fibonacci_cache:
   return fibonacci_cache[n]

   # Compute the Nth term 
      if n== 1:
       value = 1
       elif n == 2:
         value = 1 
         elif n > 2:
           value = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

           # Cache the value and return it 
           fibonacci_cache[n] = value
           return value

             print(n, ":", fibonacchi(11))
```

Comment: ".. and second i got empty result sometime when im running .." But you just said your code is *not* running?

Comment: Indentation is very important in python, your if n==1 has to start at the beginning of the line.

Comment: You seem to have "found" the code [here](http://cybergeek.org/learning-python-3/learn-python-module-3/recursion-in-python). I suspect that the point of the homework is for you to *write* the code yourself rather than to plagiarize it.

Comment: Fix the indentation as the error says you must.

Answer (score 3):

See @Alexis Drakopoulos for a direct fix to your code.  If you want to simplify implementing memoization you can use a decorator called lru_cache.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fibonacci(n):
    if n<= 2:
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonacci(n):

    # If we have cached the value, then return it
    if n in fibonacci_cache:
        return fibonacci_cache[n]

    # Compute the Nth term
    if n == 1:
        value = 1
    elif n == 2:
        value = 1
    elif n > 2:
        value = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

        # Cache the value and return it
        fibonacci_cache[n] = value
        return value

    print(n, ":", fibonacchi(11))
```

in Python indentation is everything, I am not sure if this is correct with the last lines with the cache.

I suggest using 4 spaces (using tabs) in order to be consistent.

Python looks at indentations to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for answer . What i can do when they ask print 11 is working but when im printing 200 it's stuck def                                                
 fibonacci(n):
 if n==1 or n==2:
  return 1
 return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
print fibonacci(200)

Comment: You can try printing inside your function to check where it gets stuck.

Comment: It stuck on a high number to calculate

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming in Python and to StackOverflow :-)

There are three problems with your code:

**1. The indentation:** Python needs you to pay attention to the indentation, such that code at a particular level is indented the same amount.

For code that runs after something like an if statement, you need to put the next block of code indented.  Then when you have the elif (which is at the same level as the if statement) you need to bring the indenting back out to match the level of the if.

You can indent with spaces or tabs, but you need to be consistent (ie stick to one)

It's possible that the editor you're using has messed up the intenting when you pasted the code in, and it's also possible that some of the indenting got messed up when you put it into StackOverflow too, but you need it to look like that below.  In this case, each intent is two spaces (*so indenting is first no spaces, then two spaces, then four spaces etc.*)

**2. Typos:** The final statement has a typo (so you're not actually calling the function you define!)

**3. Fibbonacci_cache:** it isn't defined, so that's been added at the top

Hope that helps - good luck with the rest of your journey into programming... it will need perseverance but you'll get the hang in time I'm sure!

```
fibonacci_cache = {}

def fibonacci (n) :
  # If we have cached the value, then return it 
  if n in fibonacci_cache:
    return fibonacci_cache[n]

  # Compute the Nth term 
  if n== 1:
    value = 1
  elif n == 2:
    value = 1 
  elif n > 2:
    value = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

  # Cache the value and return it 
  fibonacci_cache[n] = value
  return value

print("n:", fibonacci(11))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer :)